# How do I fix the error exporting data in Prestashop

Tags: xampp, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I was trying Export some data of my Prestashop site to be imported in another pc, I am using a JX MODULE [ Sample data Intall ] but during the proces to export customer data, a message in red background is displayed:

```
Generating &quot;Customtext&quot; data
```

I am waiting for a long time hoping the process continue, but is not.

Can anybody tell me something about the error?

[image: Working Fine]
[image: Error]

Comment: Try to enable debugging to see if there is an specific error

Comment: @Crezzur Thanks for your response, I am in debug mode and the same thing is displayed, the same imag. Attach you [Images/Code](https://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/VqO7093uFs9x5EZtBfYUSQ)

Comment: Did you ask the module builder already? Also please share some more info what you are trying to export and maybe a link to the module you are using.